# Including node package into Python AWS Lambda

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, npm, aws-lambda

I would like to run a node package by a python script. Specifically, I am running Python 3 on AWS lambda and I need to execute a `newman` command (`newman` is the CLI version of the postman app).

I have this working locally because I have `newman` installed globally (so I can execute the script through a python `subprocess`.

What is the ideal way of packaging up the `newman` package and all of its dependencies?

Comment: Why do you need `newman` specifically, can't you use a Python HTTP client?

Comment: `newman` is a API testing framework. It has dump truck loads more features than the python HTTP client has.

Comment: What do you mean *"the"* client? There are many Python tools. And if you want to use a Node tool specifically, why not write a Node lambda? This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: This is what the [python http client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) is.

Comment: I'd absolutely love to debate why this question earned a down vote. Its extremely practical and common that an application developed in one language would need to rely on an application written in another, different language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is fairly straightforward (albeit it can appear to be a bit odd because of the nature of combining python with js).

-

If a *node* package is absolutely necessary to your python lambda, take the time to set up a proper npm virtual env in a directory of your choice (for me, I created `executables/node`) first for the package manager to do the manual labor of gathering dependencies (use `npm init` for this). Be sure to do a thorough review of using a node lambda in addition to a python lambda before you do this.

Once the env is there, install the packages that you need (for my case `newman`) with `npm install`.

Within the directory that you chose to work in, you will see all of the dependencies and the desired node package thrown into the `node_modules` directory. From there, force the python code to call the package from within the directory. Voila... You have yourself a node package working within a Python AWS lambda context.